# Can connect one remote server to MySql, but cannot connect two servers

Tags: linux, mysql, remote-access, mariadb

I am trying to finish a website creation using three servers with Linux. For simplicity, I will identify the servers as server 1, server 2 and server 3. I am using MariaDB. All three servers are configured identically, with two exceptions. Server 1 contains the database, and the other two servers contain the website files (i.e., /var/www/html/). Server 2 is the main server (ns1) and server 3 is the backup server (ns3).

I have granted MySql access to 2 and 3, from server 1. Server 2 accesses the database with no problem. However, when I load server 3 in the address bar, the following message shows on the screen:

```
MySQL server has gone away
```

When I granted privileges, I used the following queries from server 1 for each of the other servers:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remote2'@'IPSERVER2' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORDSERVER2' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'remote3'@'IPSERVER3' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORDSERVER3' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Port 3306 has been enabled on all three servers. Finally, I reloaded the firewall, and restarted MySql and MariaDB on all three servers.

If someone can help me figure this out, I would be very appreciative.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be simpler to use the same 'user' and 'password' (but different 'host') in those grants.  As an aside, it is more secure to grant `ON mydb.*` instead of `ON *.*`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I figured it out, and in the process, discovered the importance of being very careful when coding. On the php database handling file, I entered the wrong hostname for the server containing the database. When I changed it, it worked perfectly.